# How to schedule a C program to execute at a certain time then email output?

Tags: ubuntu, email, c, time, c++

How would one go about scheduling a C program to execute at a certain time, then email the output to someone upon completion? I'm personally working in ubuntu, but even a general answer would be great (if using ubuntu matters or not).

Could the same be done in a C++ program? And if so, are there really any differences in how it would be implemented?

Comment: The language that the program is written in has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

The way to exec program (independently of the nature) is sample. You need a compiled program i.e. executable file. And the you need to add record to the cron. The record can be something like:

```
10 5 * * * /path/to/your/program
```

The above will execute `program` located in directory `/path/to/your` at **05:10** 
If you want to send mail and this functionality is not incorporated in your program you can create shell script where exec your program, redirect output to file (real or virtual) and send mail.

Comment: No need to add a script to send email, cron will do that for you.

Comment: @StephenKitt, right, but only if you run the cron with the same user as mail recipient :)

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use `MAILTO` to specify an email address and the cron result will be sent there.

Comment: @StephenKitt With the caveat that `MAILTO` is global to a user  `crontab`, if you want multiple email destinations you might want to mail the stdout of the scripts.

Comment: Of course, the word `at` *is* in the question.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP, true. But I have my doubts OP will need only one execution :)

Comment: @Rui you can specify multiple `MAILTO` values, they will be used for cron entries following them in the crontab (until the next `MAILTO` assignment).